# Find the Maximum Step in a Staircase

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures

I am solving a staircase problem and came up with multiple solutions in mind. It looks like below:

Question: You will be given number of stairs say N. What is the maximum step you can make?
For N = 5, The maximum step you can make is 2 because

> 5 = 1 + 2 + 2

Similarly for 8, its, 8 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 2, maximum step is 3
Similarly for 16, its, 16 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 1, maximum step is 5.
When the next number is less than previous then the series will stop.
Clearly, The maximum step is maximum number in the series.

Solution 1:

> I came up with a simple solution. It works fine but not optimized.
>   Below is the following code:

```
public static long stairCase(long N) {
        long i = 1;
        long curr = N;
        while (i < N) {
            curr = curr - i;
            if (i >= curr) {
                return i;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Solution 2:

> Then i figured out that its n(n+1) / 2. So, if i put n(n+1)/2 = no. of
>   Stairs.I cant get the solution by calculating its roots and taking
>   highest of the roots. My Code looks like below but it doesn't works
>   for N = 16 and many other cases.

```
int b = 1;
    int var = (1) - (4 * -c);
    double temp1 = Math.sqrt(var);

    double root1 = (-b + temp1) / (2 * a);
    double root2 = (-b - temp1) / (2 * a);
    double root1Abs = Math.abs(root1);
    double root2Abs = Math.abs(root2);
    return (long) (root1Abs > root2Abs ? Math.floor(root1Abs) : Math
            .floor(root2Abs));
```

Solution 3:

> I came up with another solution but still its not working for N = 4
>   and many other cases. Below is my code:

```
 double answer = Math.sqrt(c * 2);
    return (long) (Math.floor(answer));
```

**Does Anyone have the optimized solutions(preferably in constant time) because the input is too big(long).**

Comment: The "staircase problem" is not at all clear from your description. Please explain it more clearly.

Comment: explained..............

Comment: @ojas What determines the number of steps i.e. how big the series is? For 5, you had 3 numbers, 8 -> 4 numbers, 16 -> 6 numbers....

Comment: when the next number is less than previous then the series will stop

Comment: as i think OP means `find x such that Sigma[1..x] <=N`... for 5... 1+2 = 3, adding 3 will pass '5' so biggest step is 2 (1+2+**2** = 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m = number of stair

n = result

The equation is

```
n * (n+1) < 2m
```

The solution is

```
n < (sqrt(8*m+1)-1)/2
```

We try to find maximum integer so

```
n = floor((sqrt(8*m+1)-1)/2)
```

The Java Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int staircase(int m){
        return (int) Math.floor((Math.sqrt(8*(double)m+1)-1)/2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Result:"+staircase(16));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured the solution by myself ..I should use 2* c

```
int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int var = (1) - (4 * -2 * c);
        double temp1 = Math.sqrt(var);

        double root1 = (-b + temp1) / (2 * a);
        double root2 = (-b - temp1) / (2 * a);
        return (long) (root1 > root2 ? Math.floor(root1) : Math.floor(root2));
```